# Converting the type of a column of a pyspark DataFrame from BigInt to Int

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

when I create a pyspark DataFrame the follwing way:

```
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
      ('Client1', 'abc', 1),
      ('Client2', 'def', 2),
      ('Client3', 'ghi', 3)
   ]).toDF(['CLIENT_NO', 'CLIENT_FAMILY', 'CLT_INT'])
```

the 'CLT_INT' column is of the type **BigInt**.

Any suggestions on how I can cast that column to not contain **BigInt** but instead **Int** without changing the way I create the DataFrame, i.e., by still using *parallelize* and *toDF*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
>>> df2 = df.withColumn("CLT_INT", df["CLT_INT"].cast(IntegerType()))
>>> df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- CLIENT_NO: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CLIENT_FAMILY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CLT_INT: integer (nullable = true)
```